# Remove default group header icon of Expandable listview

Tags: android

I am not able to remove Group header icon of Expandable listview,can anybody tell me how to set it to null in xml..

**Update**

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/elist"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" android:scrollbarSize="4dip"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

and my Group header i am Using following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/zimbabwe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
        android:paddingLeft="35dip" android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but its not working for me

My `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` is:

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter( this, 
        createBetGroupList("spot"), 
        R.layout.group_row, new String[] { "BetGroup" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.childname }, createBetChildList("spot") , 
        R.layout.child_row, new String[] { "betText","betRate","betID" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.txtBetText, R.id.txtdecRate,R.id.txtstrBetID} );
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should set in your layout xml file the `groupIndicator` to null:

```
<ExpandableListView [...] 
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

Comment: still not working ... i am posted my xml please let me know what i did wrong ?

Comment: are you using a simple `Activity` instance, where you inflate an xml layout with this `ExpandableListView` declaration inside? Adding your whole layout, and the `onCreate` method of your `Activity` might reveal more about this issue. So far this seems to be ok.

Comment: yes .. i am using SimpleExpandableListAdapter in which i am binding Expanderlistview Header and child elements

Comment: SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =

new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
       
this,

       
createBetGroupList("spot"), 

       
R.layout.group_row, 
       
new String[] { "BetGroup" }, 
      
new int[] { R.id.childname },  
      
createBetChildList("spot") , 

       
R.layout.child_row,        
new String[] { "betText","betRate","betID" },
       
new int[] { R.id.txtBetText, R.id.txtdecRate,R.id.txtstrBetID} )

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please from now on share code in your question by editing it, since it is not readable in comment. Also, please share your main layout (in which the `ExpandableListView` is integrated), and the `Activity`'s `onCreate` method (where you inflate this main layout). Thanks!